# TeXshade package - ruler missing position when "-" in consensus

Tags: packages, align, environments

I am using the texshade package, and have run into a problem I was hoping someone may be able to help with.

I am using the diverse shading mode to compare mutated antibody sequences to their unmutated germline precursor. There is an insertion in the antibody sequences relative to germline. If I represent the insertion as "-", it causes the ruler to miss a numbering position at that point. Does anyone know of a way this can be corrected?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Tex code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{texshade}
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
\hoffset=0pt
\voffset=0pt
\paperwidth=8.27in
\paperheight=11.69in
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
\relax
\else
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\fi
\oddsidemargin=-0.25in
\topmargin=0.3in
\textwidth=7in
\textheight=11.62in
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\newline
\begin{texshade}{aligned.heavy.fasta}
\setsize{features}{footnotesize}
\shadingmode{diverse}
\hidenumbering
\showruler{1}{top}
\setsize{ruler}{scriptsize}
\rulersteps{1}
\shownames{left}
\end{texshade}
\end{document}
```

And the aligned.heavy.fasta file:

```
>germline_comparator
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE-EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
>seq1
EEEEQEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEETEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
>seq2
EEEEQEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEETEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
>seq3
EEEEQEEEEEEEEEEEEFEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEETEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Comment: This seems to be a feature, the _germline_ line is the reference sequence, and the numbering follows the reference, which seems to be a valid consideration. I don't think `texshade` provides an option to change this. It could be done by changing the package source, but that is a rather difficult task.

Comment: What is it that you want to do? The numbering is by default relative to the first sequence, and "-" is a gap, so not counted. If you want your numbering to include this gap as a position, then you should take the sequence that has no gaps for the numbering reference. From the texshade manual (page 58):  \showruler[〈color〉]{〈position〉}{〈seqref〉}

Answer (score 0):

You can add in a Dummy sequence on the second line with no gaps:

```
>Dummy
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

And then use the commands:

```
\showruler{2}{top}
\hideseq{2}
```

to use it for numbering and prevent it from being displayed. This will fix the numbering.